# Create selector dynamically from string

Tags: oop, selector, smalltalk, traits, pharo

I've made a program that uses reflection to add Traits dynamically, and solves conflicts automatically in one predeterminated way.

It uses aliases. It's working (I think), but I have only a problem when finally adding the trait.

My program generates all the aliases for each conflicting method, and add them with the trait to the class. The problem is that I'm not able to generate the selector correctly, its generating a string instead.

For example:

I need this

```
TCircle @ {#circleHash -> #hash}
```

but I'm generating this

```
TCircle @ {'#circleHash' -> #hash}
```

you can see the quotes in `#circleHash`.

Because is a meta-program, it generates also dynamically the selector.
How I can get it without the quotes and with the `#`?

I need to able to do something like this

```
"have the selector name in string"
obj := 'SelectorDinamicallyGenerated'.
^(#obj)
```

and get `#SelectorDinamicallyGenerated`, and not `'#SelectorDinamicallyGenerated'`.

How can I do this?

I've tried doing like that (`#obj`) but it is not working (getting `#obj`)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've found it.

It's

```
obj asSymbol
```

Comment: This is correct. Also note that `#something` is just the same as `#'something'`

Comment: yes, but when I add it to the collection of alias it explodes with the ''

Comment: yes, but for some reason that I can't explain, its different, at least at the usage. When I do
`myClass addToComposition: myTrait @ {#alias ->#selector}` works, but when I do `myClass addToComposition: myTrait @ {'#alias' -> #selector}` it brokes. Give me something as wrong message pattern.

Comment: That is right. `myClass addToComposition: myTrait @ {'#alias' -> #selector}` should _not_ work, as `'#alias'` is a String and not a symbol. What _should_ work is `myClass addToComposition: myTrait @ {#'alias' -> #selector}` (note that the `#` is before the `'`)

Comment: right, that was generating my problem, because, as the question said, I need to generate dynamic selectors for alias, to solve conflict traits. That's why I need this, and asSymbol save my life before it explodes and the universe crashes. I was getting the string in a variable, so I can't do # myVar and automatic replace myVar with the string value

Comment: Yes, right. We might have misread one another here :). I first read your `'#alias'` as '#'alias'`, hence my remark. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2):

Good you found it yourself. Maybe it is just irritating that in smalltalk a symbol is a selector. It is just not the case that there is a selector class and you could do "aString asSelector". So

```
'foo' asSymbol => #foo
```

will do. If you need to generate a setter you can do

```
'foo' asSymbol asMutator => #foo:
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, a selector could be any object, it's only the IDE that restricts it to Symbol you could just try:
 Object methodDictionary at: true put: (Object methodDictionary at: #asString).
 ^ Float pi perform: true